# Cisco ASA 5505 license, "true" interface connectivity

Tags: networking, firewall, license

So i bought a Cisco ASA and i am trying to get 2 interfaces to fully communicate with each other. Another technician here at work that knows more says that for this to happen i need a security plus license and my ASA has a base license. Is this necessarily true? Im also having issues connecting to SSH from the internet to my ASA, could this also lie under my current license? Looking at cisco's documentation on my ASA, it isnt that informative its more of a quick overview.

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa93/configuration/general/asa-general-cli/intro-license.html#20490

Much help appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Current ASA Config
http://pastebin.com/WSz8wNNv

Comment: What does "fully communicate with each other" mean?

Comment: well... ping, access shares, etc... Full communication... As if they were on the same subnet. They are on separate subnets but have them be able to talk to eachother.

Comment: So you mean you want to use it to route between subnets? For that to work, the other devices will need to know to send traffic to this device. Have you set that up on those devices?

Comment: actually at the moment im working on it and i got a device on another interface to ping the other but it doesnt  work for all devices. For example my PC on wired can ping anything on the wireless subnet but if i put my PC on wireless it cant ping my server on the wired network but can ping my linux server. It seems that pings work for some devices and not for others. not sure why this is.

Comment: Troubleshoot a case where ping doesn't work and see what goes wrong. Does the ping get sent? Does the other end receive it? Does it send a reply? Does the reply get through? My guess will be that routing tables are not correct on some of the machines and they have no idea they need to use this ASA to reach the other subnet. Do the devices' default routes point to the ASA?

Comment: every device is connected to the ASA and uses the ASA as the gateway, since it IS the gateway in my setup. I added ACL's that allow both echo and echo-reply to each subnet. On my server that wont respond to pings for example, firewall is allowing pings. i can ping the server from another pc on the same subnet but not from the other subnet.

Comment: updated answer with my current config

Comment: The config isn't all that much help without knowing which two interfaces/subnets you're trying to route between. Also, it would be helpful to know the two IP addresses involved.

Comment: did you check the config at all? there are only 3 active interfaces, one obviously being the outside leaving the 2 im referring to. IP from the wireless side trying to ping to the wired but fails is 192.168.100.8 to 192.168.0.24. This fails. but when pinging 192.168.0.13, a linux server, it passes.

Comment: I think the ASA is not the problem. Troubleshoot a specific case: Is the ping being sent out? Is it being received? Is the reply being sent out? ...

Answer (score 1):

By default, ASAs do not allow traffic of the security level to enter another interface of the same security level.  This is your primary problem.  `same-security-traffic permit intra-interface` command is required.

Usage:
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa81/command/ref/refgd/s1.html

The `ALLOW_WIRED` and `ALLOW_WIRELESS` ACLs are defined but not applied to any interfaces.  In addition, I recommend changing the ACLs from standard ACLs to extended ACLs.  Extended ACLs allow for control of traffic by way of source and destination, rather than just source of the traffic.

**Recommended Changes:**
(Updated 2017/02/17: Updating the ACLs to allow unrestricted outbound access, as per requested)

```
no access-list ALLOW_WIRED standard permit 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0
no access-list ALLOW_WIRELESS standard permit 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.224

same-security-traffic permit intra-interface

access-list ALLOW_WIRED_TO_WIRELESS extended permit ip 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.224
access-list ALLOW_WIRED_TO_WIRELESS extended permit ip any any
access-list ALLOW_WIRED_TO_WIRELESS remark *** Implicit Deny All ***

access-list ALLOW_WIRELESS_TO_WIRED extended permit ip 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.224 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0
access-list ALLOW_WIRELESS_TO_WIRED extended permit ip any any
access-list ALLOW_WIRELESS_TO_WIRED remark *** Implicit Deny All ***

access-group ALLOW_WIRED_TO_WIRELESS in interface inside
access-group ALLOW_WIRELESS_TO_WIRED in interface wireless
```

Note, that while the first rule in each ACL is superfluous, it was added to give some additional context as to how the rule is used.

**Testing:**
All output should result in "Up".

```
packet-tracer input inside icmp 192.168.0.2 8 0 192.168.100.2 
packet-tracer input wireless icmp 192.168.100.2 8 0 192.168.0.2
```

Comment: just tried it and it worked! only problem now is that while these 2 access groups are active, not neither network can access the internet...

Comment: i tried making an `access-list` that allows each subnet to any dest. ip and added it to my `access-group` for port forwarding but still didnt get access.

Comment: ACLs do have an "implicit deny" statement at the end.  An `extended permit ip any any` would need to be added at the end of each ACL, if you wish the Internet to be reachable from each of the subnets.

Comment: so in example for `ALLOW_WIRED_TO_WIRELESS`, i would have to create a second ACL with the same name but with `extended permit ip any any`?

Comment: Yes, though technically it is the same ACL.  `ALLOW_WIRED_TO_WIRELESS` is a single named, extended ACL, even it is is composed of multiple rules.  I will adjust the solution so the output is more clear.  Keep in mind that like all other ACLs, order is important.  ACLs are executed from a top to bottom order.

Comment: Alright. so actually its still the same. Before i tried pinging an address that i knew worked beforehand. I tried pinging my server from wireless but it is still failing. Rules suggested are applied and each subnet now can access the internet but the ping results are actually still the same. And the packet-tracer results in "up" as it should.

Comment: If you pull off the ACLs, what is the result?

Comment: `packet-tracer in wireless icmp 192.168.100.2 8 0 192.168.0.24` results in `Result:
output-interface: inside
output-status: up
output-line-status: up
Action: drop` So the ACL's are helping but for some reason the server wont reply... I can ping my linux server on the wired network just fine.